# How do I get CPU information by using python on SunOs systems?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpu, cpu-architecture, sunos

I want to get CPU information programatically. I already coded a solution for Linux, but I need to build a similar solutions for SunOS. Does anyone have any idea?

```
def getCpusInfo():
    cpuinfos = []
    cpuinfo = {}

    for line in open('/proc/cpuinfo').readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        dual = line.split(':')
        key = dual[0].replace('\t', '')
        if (key == 'processor'):
            cpuinfo = {}
            cpuinfos.append(cpuinfo)
        elif (len(dual)>1):
            cpuinfo[key] = trim(dual[1])
    return cpuinfos



cpusinfo = getCpusInfo();

print "Model = " + cpusinfo[0]['model name']
print "Quantity = " + str(len(cpusinfo))
print "Cores = " + cpusinfo[0]['cpu cores']
print "Threads = " + cpusinfo[0]['siblings']
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/solaris_show_me_the_cpu and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/6mbb1kq5u/index.html

Comment: the kstat command can help

Comment: I was expecting a result similar to this:
`Model = Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650 @ 2.67GHz
Quantity = 2
Cores = 2
Threads = 2`
So the model is still missing.

Comment: What about `psrinfo -pv` or `prtdiag` ?

Comment: `prtdiag` is only showing virtual CPUs for me while `psrinfo -pv` is showing the model, but doesn't give me any information about physical CPUs. I guess it is because I only have one, but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a solution in bash so it is easly portable for python.

Thanks for the help in the comments

```
CORES_F=`/usr/sbin/psrinfo -p`
PROCESSOR=`/usr/sbin/psrinfo -vp | head -1 | awk '{print $5}'`
MODEL=`/usr/sbin/psrinfo -pv | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "Model = " $MODEL
echo "Cores = " $CORES_F
echo "Threads = " $PROCESSOR
```

It is still missing cpu quantity, but in my case I don't need to save this information anymore.